# TFS Git API to show uncommitted changes

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

I am trying to find out how to programmatically discover the list of uncommitted changes to a Git repository that can be seen in Visual Studio:-

[Team Explorer - Changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcHSq.png)

I thought I would find the answer in the TFS Git API for diffs (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/diffs) but I don't see it. This API appears to refer only to committed changes. I know I can get this information from the git.exe command line but I want to use the API because I get the results as JSON.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

TFS doesn't have such API to get uncommitted changes, the only way is to use [git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) command to get them.

Comment: Thanks, getting the confirmation saves me from searching for something that can't be found. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So far the closest that I have come to getting what I want is to execute the following command, capture the output and parse it:-

```
git status -s
```

The output looks like this:-

```
 M /Temp51/Temp51Library.Tests/PersonTests.cs
 M /Temp51/Temp51Library/Person.cs
?? /Temp51/Temp51Library/ReadMe.txt
?? /Temp51/Temp51Library/ReadMe2.txt
```